# How to edit the display of date & time on order note of woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxRo7.jpg

The date / time display on the order detail page is displayed differently from the woocommerce setting.

I want to change the displayed date / time like this.
e.g.) Tuesday 28th 2019 May, 02:37 pm -> 2019-05-28 14:37

I think it would be nice to have a fix in the functions.php in the child theme.
Could you help me?

Best,

```
<p class="woocommerce-OrderUpdate-meta meta">
    <?php echo date_i18n( __( 'l jS \o\f F Y, h:ia', 'woocommerce' ), strtotime( $note->comment_date ) ); ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your time format `l jS \o\f F Y, h:ia` to `Y-m-d Hi`